# Efficient hash or something which represents a set of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, data-structures, hash

Imagine a table in SQL Server with following columns (this a simplification):

```
ID: int
Dimension1: int
Dimension2: int
Dimension3: string
Dimension4: string
...
Dimension30: string
```

Table can become large (millions of records). We often do queries like:

```sql
select ID from Table where Dimension1 = 1 and Dimension2 = 2
```

It is so easy for the SQL Server to get lost in criteria like this and pick the wrong query plan => performance problems.

I am wondering if there is some smart hash function or something similar which would allow efficiently search in the table like this? I.e. so when we want to find all records with `Dimension1` and `Dimension2` criteria we filter on some single and that would be able to understand what records to return.

Comment: It is not easy for SQL Server to get lost in trivial criteria like this, it's just that often it has no choice. Do you have indices that cover all your [combinations](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9407/5203) of filters? Yes, [you can](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/checksum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) store hashes of combinations of filter values, but that will have to be a separate column per each possible combination, so just have a bunch of indices.

Answer (score 1):

If you do this *really* often and you have some memory to spare and you are able to catch all changes to dim1 and dim2 you could do it externally.

Totally untested code C++ code

```
using DimType = int;
using DimVec = std::vector<DimType>;
DimVec dim1, dim2; // prefilled and sorted
using intVit = DimVec ::const_iterator; 

// in case we don´t have std::span
using spanV = std::pair<intVit, intVit>; 

spanV FindValue(const DimType& vec, DimType value) {
  // is_sorted(vec)
  return {std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), value),
          std::upper_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), value) };
}

DimVec Intersection(spanV set1, spanV set2) {
  // is_sorted(set1) && is_sorted(set2)
  DimVec res;
  res.resize(std::min(set1.size()), set2.size());
  auto last=std::set_intersection (set1.first, set1.second, set2.first, set2.second, res.begin());

  v.resize(last-res.begin()); 

  return res;
}

DimVec Intersection(const DimVec& set1, DimVec& set2, DimType value1, DimType value2) {
  return Intersection(FindValue(set1, value1), FindValue(set2, value2));
}
```

Add templates to generalize.

FindValue is O(lg N), set_intersection is O(N).

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
select ID from Table where Dimension1 = 1 and Dimension2 = 2
```

You want an index on `(Dimension1, Dimension2)`.  The order is irrelevant and you can include `ID` as well.

I'm not sure what you mean by "get lost in criteria".  I'm pretty sure SQL Server will identify the right index in this case, regardless of how many indexes you have.

What you might have is a more complicated `WHERE` clause.  In particular if it contains more conditions -- particularly if those conditions are connected by `OR` -- then the indexing just might not work.

I suspect your actual *query* is more complicated, not that SQL Server is getting "confused".